# Passing array with objects to PHP via Axios

Tags: php, arrays, json, axios

I am trying to pass an array with objects to PHP via an Axios post.
I'm using formData to append or set data.

```
const product_id_list = [{ title: 'hello' }, { title: 'ohhello' }]

const bodyFormData = new FormData();
bodyFormData.append('post_id', post_id)
bodyFormData.append('action', 'uploadShowcaseContent')

product_id_list.forEach((item) => {
   bodyFormData.append('product_id_list[]',item);
});

axios.post(`${__WP_VARS.AJAX_URL}`, bodyFormData)
     .then((resp) => {
         console.log('post respect is', resp)
     })
```

Then in my PHP, I am trying to loop through the array and get the title string.

```
$content = $_POST['product_id_list'];
```

The $content variable does tell me I have an Array.
However, when I do a foreach on the Array

```
foreach ($content as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```

In my console response I get **data: "[object Object][object Object]"**

When I try to echo out the title,

```
foreach ($content as $item) {
    echo $item->title;
}
```

I get an empty string.

I am stuck on trying to figure out how to loop in PHP and get the object key, value when passing it via AXIOS.

Comment: Do a `print_r($_POST['product_id_list']);` so you can see the size and shape of the array you are being passed

Comment: Also add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I get data: "Array↵(↵ [0] => [object Object]↵ [1] => [object Object]↵)↵1"

Comment: Is that Everything?

Comment: @RiggsFolly. Well yes, it is everything, but in PHP, I'm not sure how to actually grab the title key and get the value.   Even when I do $item->title, or $item['title']

Comment: Well what would be the point, `$content` contains an array of 2 object. But the objects appear to be empty

Comment: @RiggsFolly Strange, because I pass in const product_id_list = [{ 'title': 'hello' }, { 'title': 'ohhello' }], via an axios post, so the object does have a key of title and value

Comment: Use the broiwser debugger (F12) to watch what is being sent/received using the Network Tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are passing a string, many times, changing the value:

```
bodyFormData.append('product_id_list[]',item);
```

so you are actually sending a string instead of an array.
You should instead just stringify your arrays and objects before sending them:

```
const product_id_list = [{ title: 'hello' }, { title: 'ohhello' }]

const bodyFormData = new FormData();
bodyFormData.append('post_id', post_id)
bodyFormData.append('action', 'uploadShowcaseContent')
bodyFormData.append('product_id_list',JSON.stringify(product_id_list));

...
```

then to see what you are actually receiving in php:

```
$content = $_POST['product_id_list'];
var_dump($content)
```

Comment: Thanks, so I do get in return in the var_dump

"string(47) \"[{\\\"title\\\":\\\"hello\\\"},{\\\"title\\\":\\\"ohhello\\\"}]\"↵"

However, in the PHP side, I cannot figure out how to loop through this $content, even when I tried to decode it.  I can't seem to retrieve the title

Comment: Ok. Now in php remove var_dump, and change:

`$content  = json_decode($content,1);`
then in next line
`echo $content[0]['title'];`

Comment: Getting an empty string on my side

Comment: If you remove JSON.stringify(... from your js, on var_dump in php what you get?

Comment: If I remove JSON.stringify, and var_dump $content, I get in return data: "string(31) \"[object Object],[object Object]\"↵"

Comment: Cool. Try to: change the var_dump to: `var_dump(json_decode($content));`

Comment: Now getting data: "NULL↵". =/ .  Don't know what's happening, never tried to send an array with objects to PHP before via Ajax/axios

Comment: Lets investigate this. Try to put back the stringify and `var_dump(json_decode($content));`

Comment: Ah ! I tried this $json_string = stripslashes($content);  Then I'm able to $data = json_decode($json_string, true), and loop over the $data now ! : )  You set me in the right direction, so I'll mark it accepted, appreciate your help !

Comment: Super! Great it helps!